# flutter error Expected a value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, http, response

When I Map response body, it gives error.

**Expected a value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List'**

I want to print(data["id"]);

```
 var response = await http.post(url, body: mpost);
 // messageBox(context, response.body, response.body, "ok");
 Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
 print(data["id"]);
```

Comment: can you paste response.body?

Comment: [{"id":"2","message":"found"}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `response.body` is returned as `List`.

To get the id, you can use `for-loop`.

```
for(var i in jsonDecode(response.body)){
     print(i["id"]);
}
```

Comment: how to get value of  id 1 if below response  [{"id":"1","message":"found"},{"id":"2","message":" nofound"}]